# AWK: execute CURL on each line and parse result

Tags: shell, curl, awk

given an input stream with following lines:

```
123
456
789
098
...
```

I would like to call

```
curl -s http://foo.bar/some.php?id=xxx
```

with xxx being the number for each line, and everytime let an awk script fetch some information from the curl output which is written to the output stream. I am wondering if this is possible without using the awk "system()" call in following way:

```
cat lines | grep "^[0-9]*$" | awk '
    {
        system("curl -s " $0 \
        " | awk \'{ #parsing; print }\'")
    }'
```

Comment: I find this question interesting in situations where the input come from a "real" stream, not a file. For instance a sensing device that generate data (lines) periodically e.g. on /dev/ttyUSB0. In such cases, the proposed answers (reading from a file) are applicable only if storing data from the stream a temporary file and periodically process the file (what if data arrive while processing ?). But a more direct approach (using a pipe) might be better...

Comment: Note the `cat | grep | awk` can be simplified to just `awk '/^[0-9]+$/ {}' file`. Also, what kind of parsing do you want to do? Maybe it is not necessary to use `awk` at all and a `while read` loop suffices.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bash and avoid awk `system` call:

```
grep "^[0-9]*$" lines | while read line; do
    curl -s "http://foo.bar/some.php?id=$line" | awk 'do your parsing ...'
done
```

Answer (score 0):

A shell loop would achieve a similar result, as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in $(cat lines|grep "^[0-9]*$"); do 
    curl -s "http://foo.bar/some.php?id=$f" | awk '{....}'
done
```

Alternative methods for doing similar tasks include using Perl or Python with an HTTP client.

Answer (score 0):

If your file gets dynamically appended the id's, you can daemonize a small `while` loop to keep checking for more data in the file, like this:

`while IFS= read -d $'\n' -r a || sleep 1; do [[ -n "$a" ]] && curl -s "http://foo.bar/some.php?id=${a}"; done < lines.txt`

Otherwise if it's static, you can change the `sleep 1` to `break` and it will read the file and quit when there is no data left, pretty useful to know how to do.